# h5py import error on libhdf5_serial.so.100

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspbian, h5py

I have installed raspbian os on raspberry pi 3 model b. I have to perform a project which involves use of h5py.

The os already came preinstalled with python 2.7 and 3.5

With the help of pip, I installed h5py and it was successful, for python 3.5.

**ImportError: libhdf5_serial.so.100: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**

I don't know how to proceed with this error, can somebody please point out an appropriate way to handle this error?

Comment: As the error says, python cannot find hdf5 library. if you read http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/build.html under "source installation" section, three requirements are mentioned.  First install HDF5 library: http://depts.washington.edu/cssuwb/wiki/linux_hdf5_installation. and install h5py again.

Comment: A google search of your error produced this fix: https://github.com/h5py/h5py/issues/672

Answer (score 17):

I met the same question as yours, and you can use the website below to solve it: https://www.howtoinstall.co/en/debian/stretch/

In generally, you will find these commands similarly.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libhdf5-dev
sudo apt-get install libhdf5-serial-dev
```

Besides, you can visit [my blog](https://www.jianshu.com/p/8e82da85616a) about this problem. It's written in Chinese, so maybe you need http://translate.google.com

Comment: 2022, this is not working for my error caused by opencv installation.

Comment: When I install opencv on raspbian OS, I also met some errors, but they can be solved using the website above. Maybe you can try it.

Answer (score 4):

Install all of these packages

```
sudo apt-get install libhdf5-dev
sudo apt-get install libhdf5-serial-dev

sudo apt-get install libcblas-dev
sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev
sudo apt-get install libjasper-dev 
sudo apt-get install libqtgui4 
sudo apt-get install libqt4-test
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53402396/2696230