# How to solve ImportError: libhdf5_serial.so.103: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory while Importing h5py

Tags: python, linux, importerror, hdf5, h5py

I am fairly new to the Linux Platform and the Raspberry Pi. I am basically doing an ML Project with Tensorflow. So for saving the model, I am using the **h5py** library. Although I had no problems installing the library, I had a huge Import Error when importing it in Python 3.7

I used this to download `pip3 install h5py`

This is the Import Error it showed after I ran the code - 
`File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/h5py/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from . import _errors
ImportError: libhdf5_serial.so.103: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

So after seeing this error I searched a lot on the internet but nothing worked for me. 
I tried [this](https://github.com/piwheels/piwheels/issues/75), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48965309/h5py-import-error-on-libhdf5-serial-so-100), [this](https://blog.piwheels.org/how-to-work-out-the-missing-dependencies-for-a-python-package/) and even [this](https://www.codenong.com/s1190000020994149/).

I also installed `sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libhdf5-dev
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libhdf5-serial-dev`

But nothing seems to work. What should I do??

Btw, I used the Raspberry Pi 3B+, Python 3.7 and Raspbian.

Comment: Good question, I had the same issue. And welcome to SO!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had a similar problem when installing numpy on a raspberry pi zero w I could solve by

1. uninstall the library in pip
2. install the library with apt-get: `sudo apt-get install python3-h5py`

It seems like just installing the library using apt-get without uninstalling it priorly doesn't work.

Comment: This worked for me.  I used "pip3 uninstall h5py" and then "sudo apt-get install python3-h5py".